# Mule - Unable to find an StreamCloser for the stream type: class java.lang.String

Tags: mule

After the JMS message is delivered to the queue I see a log statement related to Stream Closer. It doesn't look right to me .. why do I see this message?

```
2013-04-22 19:08:29,385 [DEBUG] org.mule.transport.jms.activemq.ActiveMQJmsConnector  - Returning dispatcher for endpoint: jms://retry.queue = EeJmsMessageDispatcher{this=5c5801d7, endpoint=jms://retry.queue, disposed=false}
2013-04-22 19:08:29,433 [DEBUG] org.mule.util.DefaultStreamCloserService  - Unable to find an StreamCloser for the stream type: class java.lang.String, the stream: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> < ....... rest of the XML   ....... />  will not be closed.
```

What does it mean by - "the stream: will not be closed."?

What should I do to fix this?

====EDIT =====

There is an error happening.  The JMS message has XML as payload.  Mule version: 3.3.2

Here's my flow

```
<flow name="sendToHost">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="host.queue" exchange-pattern="one-way" />
    <copy-properties propertyName="*" />     
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="/hostmessages" outputPattern="outgoing-xml-[function:dateStamp].log" />
    <set-variable variableName="hostXML" value="#[payload]" />
    <flow-ref name="webServiceCall" />
    <flow-ref name="inspectWSResponse" />
    <exception-strategy ref="retryExceptionStrategy" />
</flow>

<flow name="resendFailedMessages">
    <description>   
        "*/15 07-18 * * ?" run every 15 minutes from 7 am to 6 pm every day -->
    </description>
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="hostRedeliveryJob" cronExpression="0 0/1 * * * ?">
        <quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
            <quartz:job-endpoint ref="redeliverToHost" />
        </quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <set-variable variableName="hostXML" value="#[payload]" />
    <logger message="QUARTZ found message for host" level="INFO" />
    <flow-ref name="webServiceCall" />
    <flow-ref name="inspectWSResponse" />
    <exception-strategy ref="retryExceptionStrategy" />
</flow>

<choice-exception-strategy name="retryExceptionStrategy">
    <catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(java.io.IOException)]">
        <logger message="In retryExceptionStrategy IO exception strategy. " level="ERROR" />
        <logger message="retryExceptionStrategy exception is #[exception.causeException]" level="ERROR" />
        <set-property propertyName="exception" value="#[exception.summaryMessage]" />
        <set-payload value="#[hostXML]" />
        <logger message="retryExceptionStrategy payload is #[payload]" level="ERROR" />
        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="retry.queue" />
    </catch-exception-strategy>
    <catch-exception-strategy>
        <logger message="Other error in sending result to host in retryExceptionStrategy flow." level="INFO" />
        <set-property propertyName="exception" value="#[exception.summaryMessage]" />
        <set-payload value="#[hostXML]" />
        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="declined.queue" />
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</choice-exception-strategy> 

<sub-flow name="webServiceCall">
    <cxf:proxy-client payload="body" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false">
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
    </cxf:proxy-client>

    <outbound-endpoint address="${host.ws.url}" mimeType="text/xml" connector-ref="http.connector" />
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer />
</sub-flow>

 <sub-flow name="inspectWSResponse">
    <choice>
        <when expression="#[xpath('//acord:TestResult/acord:TestCode/acord:Name/@tc').value == '1']">
            <logger message="Message Delivered Successfully to host" level="INFO" />
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <set-payload value="#[hostXML]" />
            <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="declined.queue" />
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</sub-flow>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log entries at `DEBUG` level can typically be safely ignored.

In this particular case, it seems Mule is using the `StreamCloserService` on a message's payload that is not a stream but a string.

Looking at the source code this can seem to possibly happen only when an exception is processed and Mule attempts to forcefully close a streaming payload without first checking if it is actually streaming. This is benign and can't trigger any side-effect so you can safely ignore this `DEBUG` statement.

Comment: David ... thanks for looking at it. I have updated the question.

Comment: I assume this is a `javax.jmx.TextMessage` (you didn't specify). Since you have an error, then this `DEBUG` message is expected. I updated my answer accordingly.